# RequestId/TraceId logging middleware for Blazor server

Tags: c#, session, logging, blazor-server-side, sessionid

I used to be able to track a specific user/request's log path quite easily in HTTP requests by adding some logging middleware to capture and write the IDs that Microsoft already generated such as `TraceId`.  Those are used to tag each log so that we can query/filter on them in whatever log sink we choose ( Splunk, Cloudwatch, etc. ).

1. Is there a normalized equivalent for Blazor?
2. I know the session id is unique enough to the user. If this is the closest equivalent, how can I extract this information from the current session? Is that the same as the Session under HttpContext?
3. If so, the directives from Microsoft on blazor server have been to not use IHttpContextAccessor in blazor server apps.. so is there a better way to retrieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Doing logs to store/analyze/manipulate data can be pretty useful and you can add an action filter to decorate the action creating [LoggerActionFilter] .

```
public class SampleActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(Ilogger MY_LOGGER, ActionExecutingContext context , IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        var username = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        MY_LOGGER .log(username)
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // Do something after the action executes.
    }
}
```

The first method will execute right before the action
and the second right after

Comment: This is Blazor. Microsoft's documentation specifically says to not use IHttpContextAccessor in Blazor apps. See #3 in my list